# Grep data in specific pattern

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, grep, unix-philosophy

MY File:

```
"DocumentCreationDate="2019-07-15T23:56:31" SampleID="1" entClassID="65535" ClientID="0" CardID="11209797""
```

Want to grep Pattern :

```
CardID="11209797"
```

The number may be different between " "

Command used : `egrep -o CardID='\"[^]"*]'`

**OUTPUT :** `CardID="1`

**Desired Outpt:** `CardID="11209797"`

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
grep -o 'CardID="[^"]*"' file
CardID="11209797"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -Eo 'CardID="[^"]*"' file
CardID="11209797"
```

Notes:

1. `egrep` is deprecated.  Use `grep -E` instead.
2. Inside single-quotes, `"` does not need to be escaped.
3. `[^]"*]` matches any one character that is not `]`, `"`, or `*`.  What you want instead is to any series of characters except `"`.  To do that, use `[^"]*`.

Comment: Your regexp is a BRE, no need for `-E` to enable EREs.

Comment: worked , resolved